# Xampp is runni8ng but .php files won't load

Tags: xampp, windows-10

I've got a strange problem. My xampp seems to run just fine, at least the control panel says so. A couple of months back I was able to use xampp properly as well. But now, if I try to load anything in htdocs the browser tells me that the website is not available.

The only things that have changed since I used xampp successfully:

I've briefly installed wampp, but decided to deinstall it again. As far as I can tell, I have removed snd deinstalled everything succesfully.

And, I'm using an other internet connection. Is there a possibility that the firewall of the modem messes xampp up?

Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

PS: I did not post the config files of xampp, because I haven't changed them since everything worked properly, so I hardly think that it is relevant.

Comment: To begin with..I have never come across a modem with built-in firewall..so..no comments on that!...Are you sure Apache server is running?

Comment: it sure as hell seems strange to me as well, but you never know...^^ yes, xampp is running for sure.

Comment: Is apache running?...Check in your xampp control panel..If apache is running.You need to start apache server from the control panel.

Comment: appache is running on the ports 444 and 8081

Comment: localhost/myfile.php...I hope that you are using this to access the php file.

Comment: yes, I do! The path that used to work was even still in the browser history :)

Comment: Are the html files loading when you use the same directory?

Answer (score 0):

Considering your problem and the information I have gathered from you.
The best solution is:
Make a backup of all your files in `htdocs`.Uninstall Xampp completely.Download and install once again.

Note:
Latest Xampp versions comes with MariaDB unlike mysql.Now some versions of MariaDB is unstable.This would create problems when you are actually working with database and sql queries.

Either download and install Xampp which comes with Mysql or find a version of xampp which comes with a stable version of MariaDB and the latest PhpMyAdmin version.

Reinstalling solves issues like this most of the time.There may have been some kind of server conflict when you installed WAMP.So an all new installation is best.

You could also try clearing the browser history and cookie as an alternative.

Comment: I will probably do that, thanks. I tried to avoid it, because doing so I have to reinstall and reconfigure Joomla. But I have wasted so much time trying to figure the xampp problem out that I'm probably faster with that anyway

Comment: If you are satisfied.Close this question by accepting the answer.Otherwise it will remain in the unanswered section.If you are looking for better options,you may wait.